# How to get the records based on corresponding column values

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table A below which has the columns "a_id" and "b_id". I need to get all the a_id's which has both (100,200) as b_id values

```
A
a_id  b_id
---- ------
1      100
1      200
2      100
3      100
4      100
4      200
5      100
5      300
```

I need to get output like below

```
a_id  b_id
---- ------
1     100
1     200
4     100
4     200
```

Comment: You need to be more precise than that. **First**: You said you need to get all the `a_id`'s, but your sample output shows rows from the original table (including the `b_id`, and with duplicate `a_id`'s). Which do you ACTUALLY need? **Second**: What if there are two rows with `b_id = 100` and one with `b_id = 200` for a given `a_id` - is that OK? And what if an `a_id` has rows with 'b_id = 100`, `b_id = 200` and ALSO one or more with additional `b_id` values?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to `JOIN` with the same table. Something like below

```
select a.a_id, a.b_id
from A a
join A b on a.a_id = b.a_id
where a.b_id = 100
and b.b_id = 200;
```

Comment: Regardless of the actual requirement (which is unclear - see my Comment to the OP), it is extremely unlikely that the solution will require a join. If an aggregate query won't do (if he needs the actual rows), a solution with analytic functions will, and it will be more efficient than any join-based solution. No problem with your answer except "You **will have to**". Why will he HAVE TO?

Comment: @mathguy, not sure understood you clearly but how can you be so sure that analytic function would be faster without a proper explain plan? Moreover, suggested solution DBMS agnostic ... it will run on every RDBMS since it uses ANSI92 standard SQL

Comment: Note - this will return only the rows with `b_id = 100` - that doesn't look like the OP's output.

Comment: Explain Plan will not help anyway; that is for different plans for THE SAME query, not for different queries using different methods. In principle you are right: one should test (rather than look at the plans); but reading the table once is almost certain to be faster than a join.

Answer (score 0):

**Proof of concept**. This solution returns all the rows for a given `a_id`, as long as there is at least one row with `b_id=100` and another one with `b_id=200` for this `a_id`. If the same `a_id` also has other rows with different values for `b_id` (if that is possible in the inputs), those rows will be returned also. The same if there are multiple rows with `b_id=100` - all duplicates will be returned.

Depending on the actual requirement (which is still unclear at this moment - see my Comment to the OP), an even simpler solution with GROUP BY and HAVING is possible - if only the `a_id` values are needed, not the original rows.

```
with
     table_a ( a_id, b_id ) as (
       select 1, 100 from dual union all
       select 1, 200 from dual union all
       select 2, 100 from dual union all
       select 3, 100 from dual union all
       select 4, 100 from dual union all
       select 4, 200 from dual union all
       select 5, 100 from dual union all
       select 5, 300 from dual
     )
-- end of test data; SQL query begins below this line
select a_id, b_id
from (
       select a_id, b_id, 
              count(case b_id when 100 then 1 end) over (partition by a_id) as ct_1,
              count(case b_id when 200 then 1 end) over (partition by a_id) as ct_2
       from   table_a
     )
where ct_1 > 0 and ct_2 > 0
;

A_ID  B_ID
----  ----
   1   100
   1   200
   4   100
   4   200
```